# Samsung Smart TV App Picture in Picture

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Have developed an app and deployed to the TV. Now I want to have the Single-Wide behavior (partially covering the screen over an underlying input, channel), but am unable to do so. Here's what I've done:

a) Put 
`body, html {background-color:transparent;}` in the CSS file

b) config.xml - tag changes:

```
<fullwidget>n</fullwidget>
<dcont>y</dcont>
<movie>y</movie> (since my app could contain some html 5 video feed)
```

When I deployed, the background just showed black. However, there is a HDMI input from my laptop to the TV which shows fine. The ESPN app works fine with that input, just my app doesn't. Pretty sure I'm missing something regarding how to initialize the background program, screen.

PS:Using 2012 Emulator and 7500 Series 60" device for testing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in config.xml

```
<srcctl>n</srcctl>
```